# How to insert values into the database using asp.net mvc code

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, oracle11g

I have a variable called

```
var xml = RestCall.xmlResult
```

I want to add the value of this variable into an oracle database table.Here is the way that I followed.

```
"UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET RESPONSE_BODY='<wq_root>'+xml+'</wq_root>' WHERE JOB_ID=74";
dbConnection.oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It inserts value.But I want to get the value of xml variable into the table.
My ultimate result in the RESPONSE_BODY field of EMPLOYEE table should be as below.

```
<x_root>value of xml variable</x_root>
```

Comment: Why is there a `WHERE`statement in your insert query?

Comment: I want to insert data only to JOBID=74 field

Comment: I must admit, I don't know much about oracle, but reading the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604) docs let's me assume, that oracle doesn't support a `WHERE`clause in the insert statement (except for subselects). Why don't you add the ID in your insert like `INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (JOBID, RESPONSE_BODY) VALUES(74, '<x_root>'+xml+'</x_root>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the WHERE clause...

```
dbConnection.oracleCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (RESPONSE_BODY) VALUES('<x_root>"+xml+"</x_root>')";
dbConnection.oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However if you want to "insert" data into an existing row, you are looking for update instead!

```
dbConnection.oracleCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET RESPONSE_BODY = '<x_root>"+xml+"</x_root>' WHERE JOBID=74";
dbConnection.oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: yes update works.But I want to insert the value of xml variable.

Comment: Then you will have to explain exactly what you want to achieve...
How does data look now, and how do you want it to look afterwards?

Comment: Btw please take a closer look at my update example, there is a slight difference from yours regarding the distinction between ' and "